# Shell: Make a command go into a separate process group

Tags: shell, job-control

When using a job control capable shell, each pipeline is normally placed into its own process group.

When spawning a sub-process from an interactive program, such as an editor, the sub-process will normally end up in the same process group as the editor.  This means that when the editor is put into the background, the sub-process will stop as well.

This is undesirable if the sub-process is a graphical program in its own right, e.g., a PDF viewer such as `okular`.

Is the correct strategy in this case to invoke (using `vi` syntax)

`:!set -m;okular %.pdf&`

I.e., force the sub-shell to enable the (job) monitor option before invoking the viewer as a background process?  (The sub-shell is not interactive when invoked by `system()`, so the monitor option is off by default.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `set -m` is one way. I can't think of a way that requires less typing (with no prior preparation).

Another way, on Linux, is to prefix the command with `setsid`. It runs the command not only in a separate process group but also in a separate session, which in this context is unlikely to matter. It the same amount of typing, but less punctuation so it might be more convenient.

Yet another way is to run an intermediate interactive shell. It's pretty awkward typing though.

```
setsid okular %.pdf&
set -m;okular %.pdf&
sh -ic 'okular %.pdf'&
```